# Query for nested Map of list of objects in spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have an entity:

```
package com.gl.successPaths.user.entity;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import com.gl.successPaths.interests.model.InterestArea;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "user")

public class User {

    @Transient
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "users_sequence";
    @Id
    private long userId;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String profileUrl;
    private String profileImgUrl;
    private String contactNumber;
    private String designation;
    private String band;
    private long employeeId;
    private String experience;
    private String department;
    private boolean isIsNotificationActive;
    private Map<String, List<InterestArea>> interestAreas = new HashMap<>();
}
```

and another class InterestArea.java as

```
public class InterestArea {
    private long interestAreaId;
    private String interestAreaName;
    private boolean isIsSelected;
}
```

and its json as:

```
{
"myMentees": [],
"interestAreas": {
    "Activities & Interests": [
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Bike Riding",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 17
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Cycling",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 18
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Running",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 19
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Cooking",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 20
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Photography",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 21
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Yoga/Meditation",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 22
        }
    ],
    "Wellness": [
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Financial Planning",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 11
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Health",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 12
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Motivation",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 13
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Work life balance",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 14
        }
    ],
    "Social Impact": [
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Educate to Empower",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 15
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Environment Drive",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 16
        }
    ],
    "Career": [
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Technology",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 1
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "AI/ML",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 2
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Cloud",
            "isSelected": true,
            "interestAreaId": 3
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "AR/VR",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 4
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Cloud Computing",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 5
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "DevOps",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 6
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Mobile Apps",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 7
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "UI/UX",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 8
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Data Science",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 9
        },
        {
            "interestAreaName": "Microservices & Platform",
            "isSelected": false,
            "interestAreaId": 10
        }
    ]
},
"myMentors": [],
"userDetails": {
    "profileUrl": "https://ghantee.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mobile-jesus-wallpaper.jpg",
    "isNotificationActive": false,
    "profileImgUrl": "https://ghantee.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mobile-jesus-wallpaper.jpg",
    "contactNumber": "9689560753",
    "name": "Rachit Kumar",
    "employeeId": 2523,
    "designation": "Software Engineer",
    "band": "Band 1",
    "department": "Engineering",
    "experience": "3Y",
    "userId": 6,
    "email": "Rachit.Kumar@gmail.com"
}
}
```

Now I want to query data for all the Users where for each entry in Map i.e. interestAreas, interestAreaName is "Cloud" and isSelected = true;

I have been trying with query:

```
@Query("{'interestAreas': {$exists: true, $ne: []},'interestAreas': { $elemMatch: {'v': '$in': {'interestAreaName': ?0, isSelected: true}}}}")
List<User> findAllByUserInterestAreasName(String tags);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to use aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "interestArray": {
        $objectToArray: "$interestAreas"    //convert to an array of k,v pair, by adding new field
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "interestArray.v": {        //query the v field
        $elemMatch: {
          "interestAreaName": "Cloud",
          "isSelected": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "interestArray": 0        //remove the added field from output
    }
  }
]);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R2FTMagumF1)

You can write this using either, [Aggregation Framework Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation) or [Aggregation Repository Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.aggregation)

```
@Aggregation("<the entire pipeline>")
List<User> findAllByUserInterestAreasName(String tags);
```

Comment: Hi @noel, @Aggregation(pipeline = 
  {
   "{ '$addFields': { 'interestArray': { '$objectToArray': '$interestAreas' } } }",
   "{ '$match': { 'interestArray.v': { '$elemMatch': { 'interestAreaName': ?0, isSelected: true } } } }",
   "{ '$project' : {'interestArray': 0  } }" 
  })
 List<User> findAllByUserInterestAreasName(String tags); is query acc to you but it works as same as @Aggregation(pipeline = {
   "{ '$unwind' :  '$interestAreas'}, { '$match' : { 'interestAreas.interestAreaName' : ?0,  isSelected: true}}"
 }) where both quieries ignore second condition i.e.  isSelected: true.

Comment: Your aggregation query should only return those which are selected as true. But it gives those which are false as well.

Comment: Can you show the expected output for your input json?

Comment: I want list of users having an entry in List<InterestArea> as a particular element of InterestArea, having interestAreaName = Cloud and isSelected = true.

Comment: The current answer returns the document as is, if it has an item `{"interestAreaName": "Cloud", "isSelected": true,... }`. This is also what I understood you wanted. Do you want the answer to also filter out all other items where `isSelected = false`?

Comment: Hi @noel, the same aggregation query works if I change 'isSelected' to 'selected' everywhere ie. in code and in database. I still do not have answer why it is so?

Comment: Your InterestArea class has `isIsSelected`, while the mongo json has `isSelected`. Maybe, this mismatch is causing the problem.